# SQL-'08: Are multiple Replace statements a bad practice/is there another way to write this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, replace

```
Select 
Distinct 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Category, ' & ', '-'), '/', '-'), ', ', '-'), ' ', '-') AS Department 
From 
     Inv WITH(NOLOCK)
```

I was wondering because I am a Jr. ETL Engineer and want to develop good habits.

Obviously this could get even longer in many circumstancials.

Comment: I am using a variant of your code to try multiple replacements in an MS Access table. It runs (with no error messages popping up), but in my replacement field (the one matching your ‘Department’, I get `#Error` returned. Any idea why? It could very well be that I should post this as a separate question.

Answer (score 5):

The nested replace is fine, but as the nesting level increases the readability of your code goes down.  If I had a large number of characters to replace I would opt for something cleaner like the below table driven approach.

```
    declare @Category varchar(25)
    set @Category = 'ABC & DEF/GHI, LMN OP'
    -- nested replace
    select replace(replace(replace(replace(@Category, ' & ', '-'), '/', '-'), ', ', '-'), ' ', '-') as Department 

    -- table driven
    declare @t table (ReplaceThis varchar(10), WithThis varchar(10))
    insert into @t
        values  (' & ', '-'), 
                ('/', '-'),
                (', ', '-'),
                (' ', '-')

    select  @Category = replace(@Category, ReplaceThis, isnull(WithThis, ''))                       
    from    @t
    where   charindex(ReplaceThis, @Category) > 0;

    select @Category [Department]
```

Answer (score 3):

You might be better off using the SQLCLR and a regex.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlclr/archive/2005/06/29/regex.aspx

Certainly that can be more maintainable and flexible.

As far as performance, you typically find it hard to beat built-in functions, but with many REPLACE operations, the CLR may outperform it - you'll have to benchmark.

I notice you said you are doing this in SSIS - in that case, you can use a variety of other possible methods within your data flows, including a script task and regex in those.  As a general rule, you need to assess each operation you are doing and decide if it should be done in the query which brings data into the data flows or in the data flow itself.  Some operations can be better to do (like filtering) on the source, but others (like aggregating), might be better done in the dataflow, especially if they are stateful with any kind of running data.