# Use Column value as string pattern in REPLACE function

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I'm trying to strip off version suffixes (`_v1`...) from a whole bunch of app names.

For example, let's say I have the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE applications 
 (
   name varchar(20)
 );

INSERT INTO applications
 (name)
VALUES
 ('MyApp_v2'),
 ('MyApp_v1'),
 ('MyApp'),
 ('YourApp_R1');
```

I could normally do this by nesting a lot of replace statements:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
         name,
       '_R1', ''),
       '_v2', ''),
       '_v1', '')
       As AppNameWithoutSuffix
FROM applications
```

But I have a lot of version numbers to check for, so I was hoping for something cleaner.  Based on the following questions:

- [SQL Nested Replace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13088921/1366033)
- [Are multiple Replace statements a bad practice/is there another way to write them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5475428/1366033)

I wanted to create a CTE that stored all the prefixes and then [`REPLACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) them all like this:

```
;WITH versions (suffix) AS (
    SELECT '_R1' UNION ALL
    SELECT '_v2' UNION ALL
    SELECT '_v1'
)
SELECT REPLACE(a.name, v.suffix, '') As AppNameWithoutSuffix
FROM applications a,
     versions v
```

But this does not quite work.  The multiple from statements gives me the cartesian product of both tables and only strips out the suffix on the rows where the value happens to line up.

#### [Demo in Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/165bb/3)

*Note*: I know I could convert this to a function, but I'd rather keep everything within a single query if possible.

Comment: +1 for trying a solution and the sqlfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does it:

```
;WITH versions (suffix) AS (
    SELECT '_R1' UNION ALL
    SELECT '_v2' UNION ALL
    SELECT '_v1'
)
SELECT  name, 
        REPLACE(A.name,ISNULL(B.suffix,''),'') VersionlessName
FROM applications A
LEFT JOIN versions B
    ON A.name LIKE '%'+B.suffix
```

The results are:

```
╔════════════╦═════════════════╗
║    name    ║ VersionlessName ║
╠════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ MyApp_v2   ║ MyApp           ║
║ MyApp_v1   ║ MyApp           ║
║ MyApp      ║ MyApp           ║
║ YourApp_R1 ║ YourApp         ║
╚════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

And [**here is**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/400cb/1) the modified sqlfiddle.

Comment: Smart! Join the version rows only on instances where they match up against the end of the name so they're guaranteed to work in the `replace` function.

Comment: @KyleMit In any case, my answer is simplistic since it assumes that there is no other coincidence of that suffix in the `name`. If you had a `name` that was: `MyApp_v2_ThisIsTheOne_v2`, then it will return `MyApp_ThisIsTheOne`.